# How to display a school Marks after a successful login from database?

Tags: android, mysql

**Background.java**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String login_url="http://www.androidiut.bplaced.net/login.php";
    String login_name= params[1];
    String login_pass= params[2];
    String method=params[0];
    if(method.equals("login")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name", "UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8") +"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass", "UTF-8") +"="+ URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;


            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if(result.equals("username or password incorrect"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(result.contains("Welcome"))
    {



        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx,Marks.class);
        ctx.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

}

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
String login_name,login_pass;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ET_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ET_PASS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);


}
public void userLog(View view)

{
    login_name=ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    login_pass=ET_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method="login";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);
   // finish();
```

1. **How to pass to Marks activity the username?**
2. **How to display Marks for the student who logged in successfully?**

***Tables***

***user_info***:(name, username(primarykey) ,password)

***Marks***:(course_name, student_username(foreignKey) , Mark)

It's my final project,any suggestions i would highly appreciate.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
bundle.putString("Username", login_name);
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
//To pass username to mark activity use 
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//Extract the data…
String name = bundle.getString("Username");        
//Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(name);
```

2. Use json to parse the marks of the student that logined in.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: Thanks i will try it ..but this code i should write it under onPostExecute method ?